# Given an index, swap array elements accordingly

Tags: arrays, typescript, performance, ecmascript-6

What I am trying to achieve is somewhat like a radio group behavior, where only one radio input can be selected at a time. For example, the starting array `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` should have its elements swapped in the following way:

| index | array |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` |
| `1` | `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]` |
| `2` | `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]` |
| `3` | `[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]` |
| `4` | `[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]` |
| `5` | `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]` |

I have come up with this, but I think it does "extra work" (unnecessary loops) in certain scenarios.

```js
function rearrange(array: number[], idx: number) {
  let arr = array.slice();
  let l = arr.length;
  if (arr.indexOf(0) === idx) return arr;

  while (arr.indexOf(0) !== idx) {
    let swap;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      if (arr[i] === 0 || arr[i + 1] === 0) {
        swap = arr[i];
        if (i + 1 < l) {
          arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
          arr[i + 1] = swap;
        }
        if (i + 1 > l) {
          arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
          arr[i - 1] = swap;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

I was wondering if you would have ideas on how to make this process simpler/better.

Comment: Can the array have any other values than 1 or 0? What should happen then?

Comment: I don't see any need to iterate when you can assign to the two indicies directly (the previous 0, and the final 0).

Comment: `if (i + 1 > l) {` is never going to be true.

Comment: Preserving values is important, yes. I depend on them at the end of the line.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You're right! I could simply reassign them accordingly. [facepalm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just identify the previous 0 with `findIndex`, assign 1 to it, and assign 0 to the `idx`?

```
function rearrange(array: number[], idx: number) {
  const arr = [...array];
  arr[arr.indexOf(0)] = 1;
  arr[idx] = 0;
  return arr;
}
```

Another approach...

```
const rearrange = (array: number[], idx: number) => (
  array.map((_, i) => i === idx ? 0 : 1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of swapping pairs, you can rotate the subarray in "one go", using slice and splice.

Here is a function that does the job, mutating the given array (not returning a new one), together with a sequence of calls to demonstrate it. I assume values could be varying and need to stay together as if they were swapped with the "moving" 0:

```js
function rearrange(array, idx) {
  let zero = array.indexOf(0);
  if (zero < idx) {
      arr.splice(zero, idx - zero + 1, ...arr.slice(zero + 1, idx + 1), 0);
  } else {
      arr.splice(idx, zero - idx + 1, 0, ...arr.slice(idx, zero));
  }
}

arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

rearrange(arr, 3);
console.log(...arr);
rearrange(arr, 1);
console.log(...arr);
rearrange(arr, 5);
console.log(...arr);
rearrange(arr, 1);
console.log(...arr);
```